# Binding XML to Combobox

Tags: c#, linq

While trying to bind XML to Combobox data source, I am getting an error "***Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource.***"

```
 XDocument obj = XDocument.Load("Managers.xml");

 comboBox1.DisplayMember = "ManagerDesig";
 comboBox1.ValueMember = "ManagerID";
 comboBox1.DataSource = obj.Descendants("manager").Select(x => new
 {
   ManagerDesig = x.Attribute("desig").Value,
   ManagerID = x.Attribute("id").Value
 });
```

Managers.xml

```
<managers>
  <manager id="123" desig="CEO" />
  <manager id="234" desig="CFO" />
  <manager id="456" desig="CIO" />
</managers>
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
 comboBox1.DataSource = obj.Descendants("manager").Select(x => new
 {
   ManagerDesig = x.Attribute("name").Value,
   ManagerID = x.Attribute("id").Value
 })
.ToList();//convert to list
```

Answer (score 1):

First, there is a typo in your example: you're retrieving the "name" attribute whereas there are only "id" and "desig" attributes defined.

Second, use [ToList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) extension method like the following:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = obj.Descendants("manager").Select(x => new
{
    ManagerDesig = x.Attribute("name").Value,
    ManagerID = x.Attribute("id").Value
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi volpav, actually it was a mistake from my side. I edited the question, while TheVillageIdiot was posting the solution.