# Populate combobox with child elements from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

I am working on a personal project and i have an xml file that looks like this:

```
   <People>
      <Person>[Mike, 43]</Person>
      <Person>[John, 29]</Person>
      <Person>[Kevin, 35]</Person>
   </People>
```

I would like read this file into a combobox and bind name to displaymember and age to valuemember on formload. Any help would be appreciated.

```
XElement rootElement = new XElement("People");
        XDocument document = new XDocument();
        foreach (var item in chk_Master.CheckedItems)
        {

         rootElement.Add(new XElement("Person", item));

        }


        document.Add(rootElement);
        document.Save("People.xml");
```

Comment: What is the platform, winform,WPF,ASP.NET,else? Have you tried something to accomplish the task? If it's Me, I would begin with structuring my XML properly, something like `<Person><Name>Mike</Name><Age>43</Age></Person>`

Comment: Its winform.  It is structured that way because I am writing to it the xml file  from a checkedlistbox control on another form.  I want the checked items on the second form to be populated in the combobox on the main form.  I have updated my original post with the code that writes to the xml file

Comment: You mean something like this?  [Binding XML to Combobox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4721436/binding-xml-to-combobox).

Comment: should I modify the above code to have my XML file properly structured?

Comment: Hi dbc, yes but I am not using xml attributes in my code.